# print Excel file by landscape orientation using Rails Spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, printing, spreadsheet, landscape

I'm using Spreadsheet gem to make Excel files in my rails application and then print it. it is working and printing too, but i need to set the orientation to landscape as the printed data is big. i tried :

```
sheet.pagesetup[:orientation] = :landscape
```

but that gave me the following error:

```
undefined method `pagesetup' for #<Spreadsheet::Worksheet:0x007f5fb240fe70>
```

any ideas will be appreciated.